# Custom roles don't behave like default roles in terms of inheritance?

Tags: sql-server

In sql server, suppose user is member of db_owner,  then, SELECT IS_MEMBER("DB_DATAREADER") returns true.

Where as if I create a new custom db role, checkmark db_datareader, now the above sql query returns false.

Custom roles don't behave like default roles in terms of inheritance?

Answer (score 0):

They do. Here's a demo showing that:

```
-- setup
CREATE USER TestUser WITHOUT LOGIN;
GO
CREATE ROLE TestRole;
ALTER ROLE db_datareader
   ADD MEMBER TestRole;
ALTER ROLE TestRole
   ADD MEMBER TestUser;
GO

-- demo
EXECUTE AS USER = 'TestUser';
GO
SELECT name
FROM sys.user_token
WHERE type = 'ROLE'
GO
REVERT;
```

That said, this statement you made:

> create a new custom db role, checkmark db_datareader

suggests that you may have made db_datareader a member of your role. In practical terms, that would mean that members of the db_datareader role would also get membership in your user-defined role. Or, looking at the UI, perhaps you made your user-defined role the owner of the db_datareader schema. Either way, not what you were intending to do.

In order to corroborate what's happening, do what you're doing through the GUI but rather than hitting "OK", hit the "Script" button near the top of the window. That will produce the T-SQL that hitting OK would have applied for you.

Comment: You are adding test role into the db_datareader. Where as my question is about adding db_datareader into test role

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "into". What behavior do you want? As I've written the demo, any members of TestRole are also members of db_datareader. That's how role inheritance works. If you do as you say and add db_datareader as a member of TestRole, any member of db_datareader will also be a member of TestRole.

Comment: You are right I had selected "user-defined role as the owner of the db_datareader schema". Please can you help me understand what does it mean to own the db_datareader schema?

Comment: That sort of thing has always been fuzzy to me. I'd be pretty reluctant to change anything about fixed db roles (aside from membership) though.